# finding biggest number in column and row within an array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, max

i wanted to make a program that can output the biggest number in each row and column.
here is my source code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < Array1[0].length; j++) {
        if (Array1[i][j] > rowMax) {
            rowMax = Array1[i][j];
            column = j;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < Array1.length; k++) {
        if (Array1[k][column] > rowMax) {
            columnMax = Array1[k][column];
        }
    }

    if (rowMax > columnMax) {
        max = rowMax;
        System.out.println("The max number is " + max + " in [" + i + "][" + column + "]");
    } else {
        max = columnMax;
        System.out.println("The max number is " + max + " in [" + i + "][" + column + "]");
    }

    max = 0;
}
```

the expected output should look like this:

> 99 28 45 62 89
>   41 85 22 12 20
>   10 11 15 13 90

the output will be **99**, **85**, and **90** because 99 is the biggest in the first row and first column, 85 is the biggest in second row and second column and so on.
but in the other hand, my program outputted like this..

> The max number is 99 in [0][0]
>   The max number is 99 in [1][0]
>   The max number is 99 in [2][0]

what's wrong in my source code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reset to 0 these variables `rowMax`, `column`, `columnMax` and `max` before each iteration because now you keep the `rowMax` value as 99.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your life a lot easier using a data structure that stores your maxima per row and column. Take two `Map<Integer, Integer>` and store the row number respectively the column number as the key and the maximum value as the value. You can refresh them in each iteration if needed. Afterwards, just print them out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] arrayOne = new int[][] { 
        {  1, 3, 54, 25, 22 },
        { 67, 2,  0, 77, 10 },
        {  2, 4, 55, 26, 23 },
        { 65, 1, 99, 88, 11 }
    };

    // data structures that hold the row or column number and the corresponding maximum value
    Map<Integer, Integer> rowMaxima = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> columnMaxima = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    // iterate over the rows
    for (int row = 0; row < arrayOne.length; row++) {

        // for every row, iterate over the columns
        for (int column = 0; column < arrayOne[row].length; column++) {
            // print the values in order to see if the iteration is correct
            System.out.println("arrayOne[" + row + "][" + column + "] is " + arrayOne[row][column]);

            // update the value of the current row's maximum value
            if (rowMaxima.get(row) == null || arrayOne[row][column] > rowMaxima.get(row)) {
                rowMaxima.put(row, arrayOne[row][column]);
            }

            // update the value of the current column's maximum value
            if (columnMaxima.get(column) == null || arrayOne[row][column] > columnMaxima.get(column)) {
                columnMaxima.put(column, arrayOne[row][column]);
            }
        }
    }

    // print all maxima of the rows
    rowMaxima.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Maximum value of row " + key + " is " + value);
    });

    // print all maxima of the columns
    columnMaxima.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.println("Maximum value of column " + key + " is " + value);
    });
}
```

> Please note that checking for `null` is needed due to an empty `Map` at the beginning, which will otherwise cause a `NullPointerException` at `rowMaxima.get(row)`.

Answer (score 0):

`Array1` has three rows and five columns. Looking at the desired output there should be three values. Your code works row by row. But the variables `rowMax` and `columnMax` are set for the whole array, not for each row or each column. Thus they are set to the max value of the table which is `99`. Since this value appears already at the first row and you're printing the max number for every row, it never changes to a higher value.

Using Java8+ streams we can simplify the logic by using the method `IntStream.max`. We can break down the overall task into two smaller tasks: find the maximum in a row and find the maximum in a column.

```
protected static int getMaxOfRow(int[][] table, int row) {
    return Arrays.stream(table[row]).max().getAsInt();
}

protected static int getMaxOfColumn(int[][] table, int column) {
    return IntStream.range(0, table.length).map(i -> table[i][column]).max().getAsInt();
}
```

Based on this we can define a method to get the maximum of a row and a column at a certain index:

```
protected static int getMaxOfRowColumn(int[][] table, int index) {
    return Math.max(getMaxOfRow(table, index), getMaxOfColumn(table, index));
}
```

Applying on your example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] table = new int[3][];
    table[0] = new int[] { 99, 28, 45, 62, 89 };
    table[1] = new int[] { 41, 85, 22, 12, 20 };
    table[2] = new int[] { 10, 11, 15, 13, 90 };

    for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        int max = getMaxOfRowColumn(table, i);
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
99
85
90
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to use `Stream` just implement the first two methods using a for-loop. You will still keep the readable design.

```
protected static int getMaxOfRow(int[][] table, int row) {
    int[] r = table[row];
    int max = r[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (max < r[i]) {
            max = r[i];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

protected static int getMaxOfColumn(int[][] table, int column) {
    int max = table[0][column];
    for (int i = 1; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (max < table[i][column]) {
            max = table[i][column];
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Please note: This code requires an array with at least one row and one column. A not initialized array or an empty array or and array with an empty row will cause an exception.

Comment: thank you for your answer! but can you also attach the code but not using the stream method? i haven't studied it yet and i don't understand it yet.